# I can't update data for my vue-chartjs Chart?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have a very special problem with my Chart.
So basically I have 4 categories of disruptions.

0 = Materialfehler, 1 = Zeichnung fehlerhaft, 2 = Material fehlend, 3 = gefertigte Rohre

In the following chart I want to create a simple graph for each category which references to the days of the week.

**My problem now: It seems to be impossible to update the chart the right way.**

Here is an excerpt of my data block:

```
 export  default {
     data() {
         return {
             disruptions: [],
             week: [],
             task: [],
             datasets: [{
                 bgColor: "#0c0306",
                 beginZero: true,
                 borderColor: "#A40000",
                 data: [],
                 //data: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 1], - for example
                 dataLabel: "Materialfehler",
             }, {
                 bgColor: "#0c9906",
                 beginZero: true,
                 borderColor: "#580000",
                 data: [],
                 //data: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1],  - for example
                 dataLabel: "Zeichnung fehlerhaft",
             }, {
                 bgColor: "#0c9906",
                 beginZero: true,
                 borderColor: "#EC4A3B",
                 data: [],
                 //data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4],  - for example
                 dataLabel: "Material fehlend",
             }, {
                 bgColor: "#0c9906",
                 beginZero: true,
                 borderColor: "#179C7D",
                 data: [],
                 //data: [3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5],  - for example
                 dataLabel: "gefertigte Rohre",
             }],
             labels: ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"],
         };
     },
```

The method getDisruptionByDay() I am using:

```
methods: {
        getDisruptionsByDay(arr, category) {
            var week = [
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                []
            ]; //Week [Sun (0), Mo (1), Tue (2), Wed (3), Thur (4), Fri (5), Sat (6)]
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 0 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Sun
                {
                    week[0].push(arr[i]);
                }
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 1 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Mon
                {
                    week[1].push(arr[i]);
                }
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 2 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Tue
                {
                    week[2].push(arr[i]);
                }
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 3 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Wed
                {
                    week[3].push(arr[i]);
                }
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 4 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Thur
                {
                    week[4].push(arr[i]);
                }
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 5 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Fri
                {
                    week[5].push(arr[i]);
                }
                if (moment(arr[i].Timestamp.split('T')[0]).day() == 6 && arr[i].DisruptionCategory == category) //Sat
                {
                    week[6].push(arr[i]);
                }
            }
            return week;
        },
```

**And this is where the problem appears:**

```
created() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/disruptions/', {})
        .then(response => {
            this.disruptions = response.data.data;
            console.log(this.disruptions);

            let week_category_0 = this.getDisruptionsByDay(this.disruptions, 0);
            let week_category_1 = this.getDisruptionsByDay(this.disruptions, 1);
            let week_category_2 = this.getDisruptionsByDay(this.disruptions, 2);
            let week_category_3 = this.getDisruptionsByDay(this.disruptions, 3);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(week_category_0));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(week_category_1));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(week_category_2));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(week_category_3));

            //start week by 1 so that the first Day is Monday instad of Sunday
            let generate_0 = [week_category_0[1].length, week_category_0[2].length, week_category_0[3].length, week_category_0[4].length, week_category_0[5].length, week_category_0[6].length, week_category_0[0].length];
            this.datasets[0].data = generate_0;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(generate_0));

            let generate_1 = [week_category_1[1].length, week_category_1[2].length, week_category_1[3].length, week_category_1[4].length, week_category_1[5].length, week_category_1[6].length, week_category_1[0].length];
            this.datasets[1].data = generate_1;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(generate_1));

            let generate_2 = [week_category_2[1].length, week_category_2[2].length, week_category_2[3].length, week_category_2[4].length, week_category_2[5].length, week_category_2[6].length, week_category_2[0].length];
            this.datasets[2].data = generate_2;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(generate_2));

            let generate_3 = [week_category_3[1].length, week_category_3[2].length, week_category_3[3].length, week_category_3[4].length, week_category_3[5].length, week_category_3[6].length, week_category_3[0].length];
            this.datasets[3].data = generate_3;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(generate_3));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.data);
        });
}
```

The console.log of the generate_'s gives the right value back as you can see in the Screenshot but for some reason the Chart interpretates the data wrong.

[image]

But if I just try it for one category everyting seems to be fine:

```
//start week by 1 so that the first Day is Monday instad of Sunday
        let generate_0 = [week_category_0[1].length, week_category_0[2].length, week_category_0[3].length, week_category_0[4].length, week_category_0[5].length, week_category_0[6].length, week_category_0[0].length];
        this.datasets[0].data = generate_0;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(generate_0));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.data);
        });
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

My HTML part looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
    <br />

    </div>

    <div class="card-img-bottom">
    <canvas id="lineCanvas" />
      <chartjs-line
        v-for="(item, index) in datasets"
        :key="index"
        :backgroundcolor="item.bgColor"
        :beginzero="item.beginZero"
        :bind="true"
        :bordercolor="item.borderColor"
        :data="item.data"
        :datalabel="item.dataLabel"
        :labels="labels"
        target="lineCanvas"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you call "draw" method on chart after data updates?

Comment: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts